# How can I make DRF Serializer create() function only create an entry that does not exist yet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two tables, which are connected with each other through a cross table. (Recipes <--> Ingredients)
My Serializer works ok, I can send POST-Requests and it saves everything. The problem ist, that every time a new Recipe comes in with let just say the Ingredient "Milk" then my Serializer creates a new entry in my database named Milk, although I have an already existing entry "Milk" in my database.
How do I tell my Serializer to use the Id of an already existing entry instead of creating a new one every time for the  cross table.

Here is how I thought I could fix it, but it clearly doesn't:

```py
class RecipeIngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ingredient = IngerdientSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = recipe_ingredients
        fields = ['amount', 'unit', 'ingredient']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredient_validated_data = validated_data.pop('ingredient')
        ingredient_serializer = self.fields['ingredient']

        ingredientDict = dict(ingredient_validated_data)

// This is where I try to check if there is already an ingredient with the name from the form
        ingredientObj = ingredient.objects.all().filter(ingredient_name=ingredientDict['ingredient_name']).
        if not ingredientObj:
            ingredient_instance = ingredient.objects.create(**ingredientDict)
            validated_data['ingredient'] = ingredient_instance
        else:
            ingredient_instance = ingredient_serializer.create(ingredientDict)
            validated_data['ingredient'] = ingredient_instance           

        recipe_ingredients_instance = recipe_ingredients.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return recipe_ingredients_instance
```

This code also seems to work, at least I find an existing ingredient, but after the last create() it seems to ignore what ever I push into the `validated_data['ingredient']` object.

EDIT
my models are:

```py
class recipe_ingredients(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(recipe, models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(ingredient, models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient.ingredient_name + ' of Recipe: ' + self.recipe.recipe_name

class recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    assembly_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number_of_servings = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe_name

class ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredient_calories = models.IntegerField('Calories per 100 Units', default=-1)
    default_unit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name
```

Comment: can you share your models also? I don't get how the `Recipe` model interacts with the `recipe_ingredients` model

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I forgot about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, finally. My mistake is this line in my Serializer:

```
ingredientObj = ingredient.objects.all().filter(ingredient_name=ingredientDict['ingredient_name']).
    if not ingredientObj:
        ingredient_instance = ingredient.objects.create(**ingredientDict)
        validated_data['ingredient'] = ingredient_instance
```

I changed it now so that it looks something like this:

```
ingredientObj = ingredient.objects.all().filter(ingredient_name=ingredientDict['ingredient_name']).
    if len(ingredientObj):
        ingredient_instance = ingredientObj.first()
        validated_data['ingredient'] = ingredient_instance
```

The `ingredient.object.create(**ingredientDict)` does actually create a new object (who would have known ;) ). This is probably still an ugly solution and I am open to more criticism but this does work for now.